# Passing argument to Java compiler in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have vscode 1.63.2, and working on a simple Java project (with no build tools). I'm using the recommended Java extensions pack. I can compile and run the project through vscode with no issues, but I can't find a way to pass a single argument to the command used to compile the .java files in settings. The command I want to pass is `-release 9`. Your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this could help:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_launch.
See the Configuration Options section (the Launch paragraph). It seems like some options allow you to pass arguments to the JVM. However, you have to configure some JSON files.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already went through that list, but could only send arguments to the JVM (using `vmArgs`) when the program is being executed, not during compilation. I'm trying to pass argument to `javac`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @UmarAbdul. try `args` instead in `launch.json`, then start debugging, you can see `'-release' '9'` in scripts.

Answer (score 1):

here is what helped me,
[https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/blob/main/Configuration.md#arguments]

1. click on arguments
2. follow the image video that you need
3. takes (the first one)String or (the second one)Array

also, you would do it in launch.json