# Enable -Xlint for VSCode Java Compiling

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, warnings

The Java extensions for VSCode do an excellent job of catching most warnings, but recently I came across several warnings in my project that VSCode was not reporting but which I found through compiling using the `-Xlint` flag.

Take this SSCCE for example:

```java
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 3;
        int y = (int)x;

        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

This code runs perfectly fine with no warnings in VSCode, but if you compile it with `javac -Xlint Test.java`, you will get this:

```
Test.java:6: warning: [cast] redundant cast to int
        int y = (int)x;
                ^      
1 warning
```

What I would like is a way of having these warnings get reported in VSCode just like other warnings (where they are highlighted with yellow squiggles that you can mouse over). I have tried, unsuccessfully, to see if there was a way of changing the default javac compiler arguments but have not found the configuration option (if it exists).

And the above warning is just a single example of things VSCode does not appear to report. I have found other warnings through using the `-Xlint` flag as well, such as fields that should be marked transient that are not.

**Edit:** I have opened a feature request for RedHat's VSCode Java extension [here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/3108).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing argument to Java compiler in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70550418/passing-argument-to-java-compiler-in-vscode)

Comment: Hey @aled, no it does not. The arguments that VSCode allows you to supply modify runtime arguments (java) not compile arguments (javac). That post doesn't help resolve my question of being able to see these additional warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode)** may be what you need.

> [SonarLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode) is an easy-to-use extension that helps you find and fix bugs and security issues as you code. The extension runs in the background and, just like a spell checker, highlights source code issues that pose a quality or security concern. The extension not only tells you what the issue is but also provides in-context guidance on why it's harmful and how to fix it, with examples. The extension supports over [500+ Java rules](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java) and includes several [Quick Fixes](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/quickfix) to automatically fix certain quality issues

- *https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting#_sonarlint*

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is what I was looking for. Thank you! I've changed the accepted answer. I would upvote you too but I don't have 15 reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [***Code Runner***](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, and then you have two ways to modify the command

1. Search `code-runner.executorMap` on the Seting panel, click `Edit in settings.json`

   [image]
2. Modify in the opening *settings.json*

   ```
           "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
   ```

   for

   ```
           "java": "cd $dir && javac -Xlint $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
   ```

   [image]
3. Right -click `Run Code (Ctrl+Alt+N)`, or the upper right triangle button select `Run Code`

   [image]

---

1. Add the following configuration to *settings.json*

   ```
       "code-runner.customCommand": "cd $dir && javac -Xlint $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
   ```
2. Use the following method to execute the script

   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Run Custom Command (Ctrl+Alt+K)`

   [image]

---

You can add the following settings to make **Code Runner** output in the **TERMINAL** instead of the **OUTPUT** panel

```
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

---

*Under normal circumstances, we still recommend that you use the [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack) to obtain more functions and better experiences.*

Comment: Hey @JialeDu, thanks for your answer. I tried this and this works to quickly see these warnings in the terminal which I like. Are you saying then that there is no way of seeing these warnings reported within the context of the editor? This is basically a fancy way of compiling the code myself, which I already have a script to do.

Comment: It looks like this is currently. If you want to see the warning on the editor page, maybe you need to install some additional extensions. Or you can report it as a feature request on [github](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks for the link to their GitHub, I think I will open a feature request for this. Though your answer doesn't really solve my problem, given the feature doesn't seem to exist, I'll give you the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you for your mark. If you submit an issue, do not forget to paste the link here so that people later can know.