# How do you change your default Code Runner execution command in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, vscode-code-runner

A newbie here, I've installed the python and code runner extension in VS code and every time I run a Python program by clicking the right arrow(run code) button, it will say `python -u <program directory>` in my terminal window. Usually there are no issues, but when I tried importing pip modules such as numpy or pandas, it will say `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Yes, I've installed those modules in my cmd and it works in my default Python IDLE. I tried many things, such as watching Youtube tutorials on how to install pip modules in VS Code but to no avail. But it turns out all this time all I need to do is just change `python` to `py` in the terminal, i.e. I need to type `py -u <program directory>` in the terminal for it to work. My question is, how do you change it so that when I click the right arrow button it just by default says `py` instead of `python` so I don't have to change it manually.
Also, another thing is when I tried creating venv with `python -m venv` or `python3 -m venv` it seems to be missing the `Scripts` folder(which contains the `Activate.psi` file) and instead has a `bin` folder. But when I tried with `py -m venv` it had the `Scripts` folder. Is this normal?

Edit: I also found out that when running `python --version` or `python3 --version`in my cmd it says `Python 3.10.9` but when running `py --version` it says `Python 3.11.4`. Maybe it's because I tried to uninstall and reinstall Python at some point in the past. I'm just wondering if this discrepancy is the reason for my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the command used by the Code Runner for Python files, change [the `code-runner.executorMap` setting](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner#configuration). Ex.

```json
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "python": "py -u",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get errors referencing packages, you should choose the correct interpreter for vscode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Python: Select Interpreter`) and use the official extension **Python** (`Run Python File`) to execute the script. The interpreter you choose for vscode does not work with the *Code Runner* extension.

It is useful for you to follow [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) to start using python in vscode now.

As for changing the command for *Code Runner*, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76251185/19133920). Although that is changing the Java command, the operation is the same.